# Is there existing integration between the Salesforce and Location modules?

Tags: 7, location, crm

I'm using the Salesforce module in Drupal 7 and am attempting to create a mapping to one of my content types that contains a Location module field. After looking at both modules, I don't see an existing integration for them.

I tried adding a field mapping for just the street address (the only method available was using a token, so I selected `[node:location:street]`).  When I kick off the import of salesforce data, I get the following error:

```
WD Salesforce Pull: Unknown data property [node. Processing failed for entity XXXXXXXXXX
associated with Salesforce Object ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I tried other variations of the token, too, including:

`[node:location:street:0]`

`[node:location:street:?]`

Both gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what's the exact problem, but I think you could have unmapped property in your configuration.
So please go to /admin/structure/salesforce/mappings and verify all the objects that have the properly set mappings and the tokens are valid.

If this doesn't help, try the following options:

1. Clear the cache (including memcached).
2. Check watchdog logs for further info.
3. Double check your Salesforce mappings again if you didn't miss anything.
4. Upgrade your [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location) and [Salesforce](http://drupal.org/project/salesforce) module to development version just to test.
5. Look for any existing issues.
6. Debug the code using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org).
7. Report the issue or bug report on [Drupal](http://www.drupal.org) site against the right module.

You may also try the following related links:

- [Location - Select User Primary](https://drupal.org/node/599436)
- [Support Salesforce attachment sync](https://drupal.org/node/1889038)